# How can I get @JsonProperty annotation values specified for Jackson for use in unit tests?

Tags: android, jackson

I've specified `@JsonProperty` annotations values for deserializing JSON to Android POJOs using Jackson 2.0.

How can I get back the `@JsonProperty` values for use during unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, it's rather messy to get the `@JsonProperty` values, as you need to use reflection for this. This quickly results in multiple lines of code to get each value. :/

Here's a better alternative:

Define a `public final static class Keys` inside your POJO to hold the key mappings. You can then use this both on `@JsonProperty` and within unit tests. Here's an example POJO:

```
// Example.java
public class Example {

  public final static class Keys {
    public final static String identifier = "id";
  }

  @JsonProperty(Keys.identifier)
  private String mIdentifier;

  public String getIdentifier() {
    return mIdentifier;
  }
}
```

The downside is that `Keys` must be declared public... per Android docs, unit tests are suppose to strip off `private` access, but I can't get access to `Keys` within my unit tests unless they are public. :/